# Mysql inner joins manage count() behaviour

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I have the following query that uses reference tables **tags_titles** and **tags_blogs** to compare against the table that holds tags in it called **tags**. Tags themselves are held in the column **t.label**.

My problem is that sometimes it **count() excessive total_matches**. Usually when the tag can be found referenced in tags_titles and tags_blogs. Is there any way to make the inner joins mutually exclusive, or other solution so that the count of actual matches to the column t.label is accurate?

```
SELECT b.blog_id AS id, b.title AS title, b.body AS body, COUNT(t.label) AS total_matches, b.creation_time AS creation_time, '1' AS type
FROM tags AS t 
INNER JOIN tags_titles AS tt
ON tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
INNER JOIN tags_blogs AS tb
ON tb.tag_id = t.tag_id
INNER JOIN blogs AS b
ON tt.blog_id=b.blog_id OR tb.blog_id=b.blog_id
WHERE t.label IN ($in) AND b.title IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, title, body, creation_time, type
```

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle example and your desired result set

Comment: I'll try never used fiddle before

Comment: Try putting the table schema used in your query and then build schema and run your query there and get your fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95647/2  does this help? Basically I want it to give +1 per match in tags_titles and +1 per match in tags_blogs

Comment: Its empty try entering some data so that we can see **it count() excessive total_matches**

Comment: Gordon beat you to it - appreciate the help though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that there is a tags list for titles and a tags list for blogs, and you are getting a Cartesian product of these tags for each blog.

The simple solution to your problem is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT b.blog_id AS id, b.title AS title, b.body AS body, COUNT(distinct t.label) AS total_matches,
       b.creation_time AS creation_time, '1' AS type
FROM tags AS t 
INNER JOIN tags_titles AS tt
ON tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
INNER JOIN tags_blogs AS tb
ON tb.tag_id = t.tag_id
INNER JOIN blogs AS b
ON tt.blog_id=b.blog_id OR tb.blog_id=b.blog_id
WHERE t.label IN ($in) AND b.title IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, title, body, creation_time, type;
```

In more complicated scenarios, you sometimes need to aggregate along the separate dimensions independently before the joins.

You have another problem which is `t.label in ($in)`.  This doesn't work for in.  Instead, you can use:

```
find_in_set(t.label, $in) > 0;
```

Or do a direct substitution of the list in SQL.  The former method does not use indexes for the filtering.  The latter will (if an appropriate one is available).

Comment: This seems to be working. Interested in what you are saying about the IN comparison...What I am doing is using mysqli and substituting a number of ?,?,? as $in depending on how many search words were entered. Is there some structural problem then with the IN?

Comment: @AmyNeville . . . There is no problem if you have a separate variable for each value.  I had the impression that `$in` was something like `'a,b,c'`.  In that case, it is interpreted as one value containing commas, rather than three comma separated values.

Comment: Yes, went through this whole torturous process of finding out how to use call_user_func_array() with mysqli - thanks so much for the help as always!! :)